# Referring to a group of files using `:ref:`

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I understand that using the `:ref:test-label` and `.. _test-label:` i can link a page to any other page.

but is there a way I can tag a group of pages and refer to that whole group using the `:ref:`?

e.g. 
I want to tag `calculator.rst`, `scientificCalculator.rst` as a `calculator` group and then refer to `.. _calculator:` from any other page to display all the pages labeled/tagged with `calculator` group (something similar to when we search a keyword and it displays all the links)

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not exactly what i was looking for, but i came across `.. index::` directive which allows me to add the keywords on my individual rsts and dispay it on the *genindex.html* page

*scientificCalculator.rst*

```
.. index:: calculator; scientific
```

*simpleCalculator.rst*

```
.. index:: calculator; simple
```

*genindex.html*

[image]